# how to insert data into model from a session attribute array in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session

I want to insert data retrieved from the `$complaint_rules_broken` variable into a table.

```
$complaint_rules_broken = $request->session()->get('complaint_rules_broken');
```

if I dump the variable `dd($complaint_rules_broken)` i get the following

```
#connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  ....
  ....
  #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "rule_id" => array:4 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
      2 => "3"
      3 => "4"
    ]
  ]
 ....
 ....
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:2 [▼
    0 => "complaint_id"
    1 => "rule_id"
  ]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

I want to insert the data from the array `rule_id[]` into table `complaint_rules`
There are 2 fields in `complaint_rules` table.  `complaint_id & rule_id`. For a particular complaint_id I want to insert all the data from the rule_id[].

How to do that? how do I retrieve the following array separately from the `$complaint_rules_broken` variable so that I can implement loops to insert data

```
"rule_id" => array:4 [▼
      0 => "3"
      1 => "4"
      2 => "7"
      3 => "9"
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `ComplaintRule` model for the complaint_rules table, and you want to associate these rules with a specific `complaint_id`.

```
use App\Models\ComplaintRule; 

$complaint_rules_broken = $request->session()->get('complaint_rules_broken');

foreach ($complaint_rules_broken->rule_id as $rule_id) {
    ComplaintRule::create([
        'complaint_id' => $yourComplaintId, // Replace with the actual complaint_id
        'rule_id' => $rule_id,
    ]);
}
```